# Reading a list of class objects from a file in python

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class named flower with two attributes, name and price

I made a list where i have a few flower objects and i wrote them into a file, how do I create a list of objects by reading the file?

This is what I have in my file:
[lily;5, rose;10]

Comment: Just so you know, your file's text is set up like a dictionary, although it is a list. If you switch the square brackets to curly brackets and the semicolons to colons, it would be much easier to code than a list, and would be syntax- correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python provides a couple of standard ways for serializing objects to file for later retrieval. The two most common are `pickle` and JSON (using the `simplejson` module).

If you're only going to use the serialized data within Python programs then `pickle` is the simpler choice. If you need to be able to share data across multiple programs, then JSON is the more natural choice.

You can read more about the `pickle` module here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

As a simple example of using a `pickle`:

```
class Flower(object):
    def __init__(self, type, value):
        super(Flower, self).__init__()
        self.type = type
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a {} and cost ${}!".format(self.type, self.value)

if __name__== "__main__":
    flowers = [ Flower("lily",5), Flower("rose",10) ]
    for f in flowers:
        print f

    pfile = open("flower_list.pickle", mode="wb")
    pickle.dump(flowers, pfile)
    pfile.close()

    pfile = open("flower_list.pickle", mode="rb")
    recalled_flowers = pickle.load(pfile)
    pfile.close()

    for f in recalled_flowers:
        print f
```